# Fatal error en PHP

Tags: php, base-de-datos, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

Cuando quiero ver un proyecto en php y pongo en el navegador localhost/viveamazonas *(vive amazonas es la carpeta donde tengo los archivos del proyecto)* sale el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Testimonios' not found in
>    C:\xampp\htdocs\ViveAmazonas\system\core\Loader.php:303 Stack trace:
>    #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ViveAmazonas\application\controllers\main.php(29):
>   CI_Loader->model('Testimonios') #1
>    C:\xampp\htdocs\ViveAmazonas\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(308):
>    Main->__construct() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\ViveAmazonas\index.php(202):
>    require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 {main}
>
> thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ViveAmazonas\system\core\Loader.php on line
>   303

Este es mi código:

```
[load->database(); } function getTestimonios(){
 $this->db->from('testimonios');
 $response = $this->db->get();
 if ($response->num_rows() > 0) { 
return $response->result_array();
 }else{ return 0; } 
} function getLastTestimonio(){
 $this->db->from('testimonios');
 $this->db->order_by('id_testimonio', 'desc'); 
$this->db->limit(1);
 $response = $this->db->get();
 if ($response->num_rows() > 0) {
 return $response->result_array();
 }else{ return 0; }
 } function getTestimoniosById($id_testimonio){ $this->db->from('testimonios');
 $this->db->where('id_testimonio', $id_testimonio);
 $response = $this->db->get(); if ($response->num_rows() > 0) { return $response->result_array();
 }else{ return 0; } 
} function modifyTestimonio($id_testimonio, $data){
 $this->db->where('id_testimonio', $id_testimonio);
 return $this->db->update('testimonios', $data);
 } function setTestimonio($data){ 
$this->db->insert('testimonios', $data);
 } function deleteTestimonio($id_testimonio){
 $this->db->where('id_testimonio',$id_testimonio);
 if($this->db->delete('testimonios')){
 return 1; }else{ return 0; }
 } 
}
```

*Captura de pantalla del error:*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta poner un poco mas del codigo de ese archivo ya que se puede ver que falta al comienzo, y donde es que llamas a la clase Testimonio

Comment: se ve que esta buscando una clase pero no la encuentra

Comment: Al iniciar tu codigo abres un corchete, pero no se ve donde lo cierras. Ayuaria un poco mas de codigo. Saludos.

Comment: A mí me suena a que el archivo testimonios.php ( si es que existe) tiene mal puesto el nombre de la clase o su namespace. Revisa ese archivo y compartelo, a ver si van x ahí los tiros

Comment: [Como dice @Jakala](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/195597/fatal-error-en-php#comment367214_195597), el loader no ha podido cargar la clase llamada `Testimonios`, sea porque no se llama así, o porque el archivo no se encuentra en el lugar correcto, donde el loader debe encontrarla y cargarla. El error es claro: *`Class 'Testimonios' not found...`*  y aquí indica que el loader no la pudo cargar: *`thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ViveAmazonas\system\core\Loader.php on line 303`*

Comment: ya pude solucionar el problema amigos , muchas graciass